# spring Rest APIcall working fine locally but failing on production

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-rest

I have a rest endpoint http://abc-xyz.doamin.com.au:8443/myapplication/v2/test I consume this in my program which is working fine locally but failing in production

**Exception**

```
"message":"HTTP exception while calling TnDM",
"logger_name":"com.myapp.resource.MyResource",
"thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-7",
"level":"ERROR",
"level_value":40000,
"stack_trace":"org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error\n\t
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:89)\n\t
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:708)\n\t
at
```

**locally works fine with 200 OK**

```
{
    "text": "Hello_Message"
}
```

**Code**

```java
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HelloWorldRequest req = new HelloWorldRequest();
    request.setName("myName");

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(req, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: your local response says it is json object of a particular type. `{"text":"your message"}` but in your `ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);` , you are setting it as `String.class`. Can you change this with `    
 `ResponseEntity<YourResponseType> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, YourResponseType.class);` ?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pojo to cature the response type you have mentioned above:

```
public class Response
 {
    private String text;
    //getter, setter
 }
```

Then change this line:

> ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(url,
>   HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

with this:

```
ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Response.class);
```

Hope, this will work!